# How to invoke 'Add Line Item' standard action from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I want to invoke Quote Line Item's 'Add Line Item' standard action from a custom LWC.
I have tried below code but it's not working.

this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

```
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'QuoteLineItem',
            actionName: 'AddQuoteLine'
        }
    });
```

Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({

        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'QuoteLineItem',
            actionName: 'new'
        }
    });
```

According to the documentation here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_page_reference_type

The valid values are only `home`, `list`, and `new`.

Comment: It will open the standard new page but I need to open the 'AddQuoteLine' page.




                                                                                                                                      Standard Action -

Label- Add Line Item, Name- AddQuoteLine.

Plz help on this.